# Our help center has nothing saying what's on topic

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic, help-center

The [on-topic page in our Help Center](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) currently looks like this:

[image]

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Programming Language Design and Implementation Stack Exchange, [...]

It never says what is on-topic for PLDI.

What is, and can this be added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the typical out-of-the-box on-topic page for a Stack Exchange site. When a site launches, this page isn't typically changed to suit the site so as to allow the community to come together and discuss how it should look.

This page is editable by moderators, so once we get some we can workshop how it should look here on Meta and ask a moderator to edit it for us. Seeing as we're still a young site, I'd hold off on defining how it should look until we're more comfortable and experienced with the types of questions that are going to be asked here.

Comment: Then you get the person who says "but the help center never said my question was off-topic" and their correct

Comment: Topicality is still fluid for this site. The link may not explain what's on-topic and what's not, but the ability for users with the close votes privilege also includes the ability to guide what's on-topic. Just because there's not a help center to support closure of your question doesn't mean it shouldn't be closed, @Starshipisgoforlaunch

Comment: I think one of the valid underlying complaints is that the scope-related off-topic close reason points to this page during private beta... and it says nothing :P

Comment: Yeah... Unfortunately, that's gonna be how it is for a bit longer. Unless we wanted to ask a CM to do it for us...

Comment: Could we since I think its quite important @Spevacus

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Technically you could, but you really shouldn't. And I suspect a CM will tell you that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have just updated the page with a draft of some site-specific on-topic criteria. I think this is sufficient to call this particular question [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but more discussion is likely necessary to further refine what we have. If you have thoughts about that, [please weigh in by posting an answer here!](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/what-should-we-explicitly-call-out-as-on-and-off-topic-in-our-help-center)