# Are linters, formatters, and static analysis tools on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Since we are [refining our site scope](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/what-should-we-explicitly-call-out-as-on-and-off-topic-in-our-help-center)

Linters, formatters, and static analysis tools parse code, build ASTs and peform other steps similar to a compiler and interpreter, but then either simply output in the same language as the input or just output some statistics or metadata.

Would questions specifically about designing and implementing these types of tools be on topic for this site? Where should the limit be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes.** Tooling design and implementation questions are on-topic. Tooling usage questions are not.

The line between compilers and other types of tooling can be very fuzzy, and I don’t know that it’s even possible to pin down where one ends and the other begins. They both require many of the same basic techniques—parsing, syntactic analysis, program transformation, etc.—and they both require programming languages expertise.